# Which exchanges allow me to transfer funds from my CurrencyFair account?

Tags: exchanges

[Update: In July, 2013 CurrencyFair has stopped allowing [delivery of funds to any Bitcoin exchanges](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1jcjtm/statement_from_currencyfair_regarding_them/).]

I can add funds to my [CurrencyFair](http://currencyfair.com) account via a bank transfer from a number of countries.  This will be a convenient method if I can then send those converted funds as a bank wire transfer to a Bitcoin exchange.

TransferWise used to allow me to do the same thing, but then stopped after their banking partners "[weren't comfortable with Bitcoin](http://transferwise.com/blog/2013-04/notice-to-bitcoin-users-april-2013)".

Are there any exchanges which allow this?

Comment: Here's a good reddit post with comments on the subject: http://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinUK/comments/1b8rug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all bank wire transfers contain the same information so this may vary based on which bank wire network is used.

For instance, CurrencyFair may function as a method to add funds from a UK account (GBP) using a bank wire and then after conversion to EUR make a withdraw as a SEPA wire transfer to [BITSTAMP.net](http://bitstamp.net), or [Mt. Gox](http://mtgox.com), and any other exchange that accepts SEPA transfers.